# Two separate models, need unification

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

We have 2 tables of models, which share the same queries, but since we query them separately, paging can be a headache.

We have the Video model and Image model.
So if we want to fetch them based on creation date, we need to run 2 queries separately, and then to unify them, re-sort and limit again.
The headache is when pagination as well, we need 2 seperate offsets for each.

You get the point.
We want to unify them somehow. Problem is that they are so rooted in our complex application, that we can't unify them into 1 big table.
We were wondering what kind of solution ActiveRecord has, if at all, to manage a single table, pointing to 2 separate models, where queries can run together. Perhaps we should create a big Assets table, where it has its own ID, and a reference_id to the particular model?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

ActiveRecord::NestedAttributes might work for you.

`class Video
  has_one: image
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :image
 end`

`params = { video: { name: 'video', image_attributes: { icon: 'image' } } }
 video = Video.create(params[:video])
 video.avatar.icon # => 'image'`

For more info: Check [this link](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/16727957)

Comment: Done that. Thanks for the info

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what database you are using, but I faced similar problem and SQL views appeared to be solution. Just create view that will union those two tables in migration file and new model representing both images and videos. In your model you need to specify table name and primary key:

```
self.primary_key = :id
self.table_name  = 'name_of_your_view'
```

ActiveRecord will treat this view as a regular table. Maybe the performance is not as good as when you have real table, but much better than loading everything into memory, sorting and paginating.

Comment: I thought about this, but i prefer not to, as the columns are constantly changing between models, require me to change the view